# Windows 7 starter will not shutdown or logoff

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, logoff

Im having some problems with a friends netbook (a dell mini 10). It will not shutdown or logoff via the usual route. Whenever the shutdown/logoff button is clicked, it will briefly freeze (maybe for only a second) and then do nothing. Ive tried shutting down manually via the command line using `shutdown /p` but all to no avail, it just defaults back to flashing cursor in the command prompt. There doesnt seem to be any mention of a similar problem on google so i was wondering if anyone else had any ideas.

Thanks

oh and its runnning windows 7 starter.

Comment: If you hold down the power button for about 5 seconds (or until it turns off) and then start it up again, are you then able to use the shutdown button?

Comment: Windows 7 *STARTER* --- They removed the shutdown feature from your version to save you money :P Jokes.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is some process responding badly to the shutdown process (canceling the shutdown when notified about it).

The best you can do is to kill process manually from the Process Explorer one by one and trying logoff after each kill. Once the logoff will succeed, you know the last process you have killed before was the one causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does running the command Work?

```
shutdown -s -f
```

If so, it's a process stopping it from shutting down rather than a driver. The "F" switch forces Windows to drop everything and shutdown, usually.